# Set static IP on Ubuntu Core

Tags: networking, ubuntu-core, static-ip, nmcli

I'm new to Ubuntu Core. On first login I selected the option:
    Will use DHCP for IPv4

Now I'd like to change my machine to use a static IP to be easier to log in remotely.

I ran `sudo console-conf` on the machine (over ssh, if relevant). This gives me the option to select `Use a static IPv4 configuration`, which I do.

This gives me the fields `subnet`, `address`, gateway`,`name servers`, and`search domains`. What should I set for these fields? I would like my IP address to be 192.168.1.101. It is currently 192.168.1.13 from DHCP. My chosen IP address is pretty arbitrary, but I'm going to have a group of computers that I'd like to have the IP addresses 192.168.1.1XX.

I'm used to setting my subnet to `255.255.255.0`, but I get the error message: `should be in CIDR form (xx.xx.xx.xx/yy)`. I'm not sure what this means or how to fix it. When I try adding `/24` at the end of the subnet, the error message goes away and I get a new error message: `'192.168.1.101' is not contained in '255.255.255.0/24'`.

Update:
[Here is a screenshot of the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Royay.png)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! `CIDR` notation is used for the IP address, not the netmask, have you tried `192.168.1.101/24`?

Comment: Thanks @MrShunz. I tried adding the CIDR to the IP address but it won't let me type in the `/` character. I attached a screenshot of the error message, in case it helps anyone.

Comment: For the subnet, please try: `192.168.1.0/24` Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015632/ubuntu-core-wifi-configuration-issue

Comment: Just to clarify the solution that was given. The mistake is that subnet 192.168.x.x/x is being confused with the subnet mask (usually 255.255.255.0). A quick explanation is that the ip4 address including the cidr (the number after /) tells us what the mask should be and so can be omitted. So for the point of completeness, a bit of light reading can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork if you want a deeper dive into IPv4 subnetting.

Comment: I advice to configure dhcp on router so it give preferred ip based on mac, if that possible in router settings

Answer (score 37):

Thanks to @MrShunz and @chili555 in the comments. These are the settings that worked for me:

`Subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
Address: 192.168.1.101
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Name servers: 8.8.8.8`

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wonder why they do it this way when everyone who has ever entered a manual IP address expects SUBNET to be a 255 address...

Answer (score 1):

If your router gateway is 192.168.0.1 you can use the following that worked for me:

subnet: 192.168.0.0
address: 192.168.0.101
gateway: 192.168.0.1
name servers: 1.1.1.1