# Problems with SSH, I also can't ping any websites or local devices on the network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, proxy

I have an ethernet cable connected to the router and I set up the ubuntu server with the IP 192.168.1.123 using the installation of Ubuntu Server 20.04 Manual IPv4.
I used [Set static IP on Ubuntu Core](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073244/set-static-ip-on-ubuntu-core) and tsteiner answer. This finally worked for installing apt-get commands such as upgrade and update. I am not sure if I set it up right. I really just want to setup a server I can use but access from my desktop computer.

The commands ifconfig, route, and arp all tell to install net-tools which I can't because it can't contact the internet. Sorry

IP Address says enp0s7
inet 192.168.1.123/24 bed 192.168.1.255 scope global enp0s7
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::7285:c2ff:fe5a:9ae5/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

IP Route
default via 192.168.1.254 dev enp0s7 proto static
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s7 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.123

Also I know I don't have a proxy setup for it and I really don't know how. I know about it being in the /etc/something.

The Subnet that is showing is 255.255.255.0 but then I need it in the CIDR form which it says doesn't exist for 255.255.255.0

Comment: Maybe you need to add a default route. If you could share the output you get from the `ifconfig` and `route` and `arp` commands, that could provide useful clues.

Answer (score 0):

The `route`, `arp` and `ifconfig` commands are a bit old-school - nowadays on Linux there are the `iproute2` suite of commands:

Try running:

```
$ ip address
$ ip route
```

You definitely want to see an IP address to configured on your network device, but also check that the netmask is correct. In a home network, I would expect the mask to be either `/24` or `/16` - corresponding to either a class C (ex: `192.168.0.x`) or class B (ex: `192.168.x.x`) network. If it's `/32` (I expect not) then that's definitely wrong!

In the routes, you want to see a default route set to the the router IP in that network - commonly ending in either `.1` or maybe `.254` but starting with same values as your server IP.

You generally should not need a proxy set up, that's also pretty old-school and/or for super-restrictive networks.