# Unable to ssh into ubuntu core on NUC

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-core

I have installed Ubuntu Core (ubuntu-core-22-amd64.img.xz) on a NUC. Using these instructions: https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/install-nuc.

When I get the screen, which is similar to when I have successfully booted a server. I am unable to ssh in.

I have created my Ubuntu One account. And loaded a public key (which does not have a passphrase). I went as far as to spin up two VirtualBox instances using the tutorial above. And was able to SSH to both VMs with the public key on my Ubuntu account.

Here is what I get when attempting to ssh to the physical NUC, not the VM. As with the VMs I can successfully ssh in.

`ssh -vvvvvvvv -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_ubuntu_core xxxxxx@xxx.xx.xx.x`

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/x/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/x/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xx.xx.x is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/x/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/x/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xx.xx.x [xxx.xx.xx.x] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address xxx.xx.xx.x port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.x port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: `Operation timed out` suggests that you are trying to connect to the wrong IP address. Maybe a typo, maybe across a router, couple other network-related (not ssh-related) maybes.

Comment: Understood. I will try to get access to a wired connection. What is odd is that when installing Ubuntu Core there were no issues connecting to the Wi-Fi network.

Comment: If you have access to the router providing that wi-fi network's DCHP, you may be able to find it among the listed clients.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not. I only have "coffee shop" Internet access. I even called a local maker space and they don't have wired access. I will re-install Ubuntu Core and disable DCHP using this suggestion: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073244/set-static-ip-on-ubuntu-core. Hopefully, this will be the work around of the SSH issue.

Comment: "*coffee shop Internet access*" (whatever that means) suggests a network owner who might be filtering or preventing inbound ssh connections. It's among those  other network-related maybes. Perhaps your question should explain more about your curious network.

Comment: Meaning: library, coffee shop, co-working space, and the place I live. I am not permitted to touch the router. Only the libraries prevent ssh. Everywhere else I can ssh, including hotspoting from my mobile phone. I wouldn't have asked this question if all other distros had this issue. If static IP doesn't work I'll need to reach out to a professional. I really want to know why Core distro has the issue and no other. Even if it is a network issue. It's a learning opportunity.

Comment: Regarding explaining my network. I'll return after I test at each location, so I come back having done the diligence, exception is the library - they block ssh. At the time of this post, I was using my mobile phone hotspot. Which I have been using without any SSH issues, until Ubuntu Core.